# Get Facebook Category ID from Category Name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able to access my page's category name through the following endpoint:

```
v2.8/me/accounts?fields=category,category_list
```

Category returns a string (the name of the category), and category_list returns an array of {id,name} properties. Unfortunately I've noticed that for some of my pages, the category_list attribute is not returned, leaving me with only the category name.

Is there a way to get the category ID of a category from the Facebook API when I only know the name of the category?